# Opacity doesn't get set on hover

Tags: jquery, css

I have a basic dropdown menu. When I hover over the different menu-choices, It's supposed to set `opacity: 1`. It's starting at `.5`.

Here's the hover-part of my jQuery:

```
$('#cat1 > li > a').hover(function () {
    $(this).css({
        color: '#dc692e', opacity: 1
    });
}, function () {
    $(this).css({
        color: '#fff', opacity: .5
    });
});
```

Here is the full fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Nilzone/HnmHh/

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I fixed your fiddle. At least *try* to use the tools available. http://jsfiddle.net/HnmHh/1/ Just using "JSHint" gives you bunch of errors. Also, why aren't you using CSS for this?

Comment: It would be better if you also explained what you _think_ is happening instead of simply saying what you _would like_ to happen.

Comment: like above, I would use RGBA

Comment: Any reason not to use css `:hover` selector?

Comment: @Tommi not really no. It's just that Im new to jQuery and wanted to use that as much as possible :)

Comment: Don't. CSS **is** the tool you should use for this.

Comment: And the reason why you don't see `opacity: 1` on `a` hover is because you delegate event before ajax call completed and menu exists. This is commmon mistake and this is why better to use css in this particular case.

Comment: @BramVanroy - What do you mean by "fixed"? Your version still doesn't do what the OP wants it to. The bunch of JSHint "errors" you mention are almost all warnings, not errors.

Comment: @nnnnnn No, but any syntax errors that were in his code have been cleaned up. That's what I mean with fixed. Else I would have posted an answer and not a comment.

Comment: @BramVanroy and thank you for that. I went over all my mistakes. for got some ';', but mostly it was just 'mixture between space and tabs' so I had to delete the line and retype it, not really a mistake in my book, but thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `$('#cat1 > li > a').hover(...` doesn't work because at the time that that code runs the `a` elements don't actually exist yet. You need to either run that code immediately after appending those elements (within the `$.getJSON()` callback), or use a delegated event handler on an element that exists initially:

```
$('#cat1').on({
    mouseenter : function () {
      $(this).css({
        color: '#dc692e', opacity: 1
      });
    },
    mouseleave : function () {
      $(this).css({
        color: '#fff', opacity: .5
      });
    }
},'li > a');
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/HnmHh/11/

The selector `'li > a'` passed as a separate parameter to `.on()` is tested each time the events occur, so the handlers work on dynamically added elements.

You wouldn't have this problem if you used CSS for this instead, because CSS rules will apply to dynamically added elements.

Comment: Worked like a charm, thank you.But based on other comments I really should use CSS for this instead!

Edit: Also, very good explanation!

Comment: Thanks. Yes, CSS is the way to go for this sort of effect, but it is important to understand the principle involved in getting the JavaScript solution to work, because that will apply to other cases where CSS can't help you. People frequently ask questions about why their event handlers don't work on dynamically added elements.

Answer (score 0):

you can use animate to change the opacity.

```
$('#cat1 > li > a').hover(function () {
    $(this).animate({opacity: 1}, 500);
});
```